# How to connect sharp edge with smooth one?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, topology

For me, the hardest part is usually connecting creased edges with non creased (or sharp surface with smooth one). I am always trying to use proximity loops technique explained by Jonathan Williamson here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBkwodrQq_4

Currently I am working on model in the picture below.
[image: object mode picture].

What I need to achieve, is to have sharp edge at the place in green circle and smooth surface on the area in red circle. 
[image: circled]

Topology details in edit mode. 
[image: Topology details in edit mode]

However with this kind of topology, the edge is sharp all along it's length. I am not sure if there is some plugin that can arrange edges so that even edges that are very close together can form smooth surface (something like circle in loop tools), calculating the adjacent edges.

Comment: you can try to bevel the sharp edge only (ctrl+B, mousewheel to add levels, move for sizing) without added loops

Comment: see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23686/custom-hard-edges-in-blender

Comment: I try that as well, but the result doesnt look good unfortunately... (don't know how to post picture in reply)

Comment: just forgot to mention that I wish to stick with supporting edge loops, no creasing or edge split, if pssible...

Comment: try sliding the supporting edges apart on the wide section so they can be subdivided better

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn't work too. It leaves ugly line on the smooth surface. See here: http://s23.postimg.org/ih60cfd8b/line.jpg

Comment: @could you upload at least this part of the mesh

Comment: just merge them on the flat surface, it will give you two small triangles, but nothing to serious.

Comment: basically you need to correct the [flow of the mesh](http://cgcookie.com/blender/lessons/controlling-topology-flow/) before adding the supporting edges

Comment: Ok, here is the *.blend file of part of the mesh, please teach me :) I am running out of ideas... thx

http://www.filedropper.com/mesh

Comment: @salamun i'm not sure if it's only me but the file seems to be corrupted? if it is try this [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/)

Comment: @Chebhou - here it is: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34362

Comment: @salamun use smooth vertex on the "12" verticies on the wide section "inside the red circle" , i can't upload any file i'm having a problem

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is separate the edge loops on the side you want smooth. Think of it as the opposite of proximity loops, where proximity loops make edges sharper, spreading out the edge loops will make it softer.

Simply select the vertices on the side you want smother, and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to edge slide them in to place.
If you get any shading artifacts, switch to side view and make sure all the edges and vertices are aligned. Scale to 0 on (an example) the Z axis to re-aline. For example, if you lowered one of the vertices, that will create a dip in the subdivided mesh and break the smooth look.

The vertices I moved are selected in this image.
[image: mesh in edit mode with vertices selected]

Edited mesh in object mode
[image: edited mesh in object mode]
[image: edited mesh in object mode]

Comment: this has been discussed before. It might be a solution in some cases, but in this case, it leaves ugly line paralell to the long edges (if you turn smooth shading on). Please check this picture here: s23.postimg.org/ih60cfd8b/line.jpg

Comment: @salamun I did have smooth shading turned on, and I know about the artifacts; but if you are careful to keep the edges alined it *does* work. http://i.stack.imgur.com/p2lio.png

Comment: Wow, it does look nice. So what should I align the edges to, to achieve result as you did?

Comment: thx. I noticed the bloody line is still there, it's just a matter of camera angle. Also, reflective materials make it even more visible: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/83732

Comment: @salamun With the topology in your mesh, you can either add space between the three loops causing the problem, or add a edge loop between the crease and the next edge loop. 

However I would have the topology completely different in that section. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qkjN0.png You want the face loops to flow around the sharp seam.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Although it's not perfect, you may try it.
Here's the .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34364
[image]
[image]

Comment: ...interesting :) Looks good too